# Is there a way to write a regex for po box and rr box in angular?

Tags: angular, regex

I need to validate an street address field and if the address contains any of the following:

```
 RR # Box #  | Personal Mail Box | PMB # | PO BOX
```

I did some research and tried to create my own regex and extend it but could not get far and looking for some input.

Here's what I have so far

```js
const regex = '\bP(ost|ostal)?([ \.]*(O|0)(ffice)?)?([ \.]*Box)\b/i'
```

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This regex would work for your example:

```js
const regex = /(RR \d{1,} Box \d{1,})|(Personal Mail Box)|(PMB \d{1,})|(PO BOX)/i
```

I've created an executable regex here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XX4MR3/1)

#### Explanations

`\d{1,}` matches for at least 1 digit. If you know, that e.g. the number behind `RR` must be between 3-6 numbers, you must change the regex as follows:

```js
const regex = /(RR \d{3,6} Box \d{1,})|(Personal Mail Box)|(PMB \d{1,})|(PO BOX)/i
```

Furthermore, if my suggestion is correct, you're using javascript. In this case, you have two ways of defining the regex: 
a)

```js
const regex = /pattern/flags
```

b)

```js
const regex = new RegExp('pattern', 'flags')
```

Read more here: [Mozilla Regex Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?retiredLocale=de)